# Retrieve the filter records from access table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table call "TG" and filter a column call "system" and 10 records remain. Is the any method or way to read the filtered results such as "ID" (in access table) for data processing?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.Openrecordset("TG")
For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
Debug.Print rs.Fields("ID")
rs.MoveNext
Next i

rs.Close
Set rs 
db.close
```

Comment: The intent of this site is not to have others write code for you. If you ask a question linke this, please provide code or options that you have already considered and focus on the specific issues you are stuck with.

Comment: opps. sorry. my bad.
i actually write some codes. 1 testing able to print out the ID. however, it doesn't print the filtered results. is there any idea?

Dim i As Integer
Dim strSQL As String    


Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.Openrecordset("TG")


For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
    Debug.Print rs.Fields("ID")
    rs.MoveNext

Next i

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close

Comment: Amend the question with this info by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

try this before entering into loop

```
rs.moveLast ' thats because access won't know the total result row count until you scroll to the end.

dim TC as long
tc = nz(rs.RecordCount,0)

rs.moveFirst ' Moving back to the first result set
For i = 0 To tc - 1
Debug.Print rs.Fields("ID")
rs.MoveNext
Next i
```